# How to navigate from xib to storyboard programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard

```
UIStoryboard *view3 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

View3ViewController *view_3 =[view3 instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"view3_id"];

[self.navigationController presentViewController:view_3 animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Could you please show more effort posting any explanation, question, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can load storyboard file

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
```

and load controller from storyboard:

```
UIViewController *vc = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myViewController"];
```

and present this controller

```
vc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```